# Salesforce API to get a record throws error Invalid Session

Tags: api, get, salesforce, apex

I am using standard way of getting a record using API. 
It works from workbench. 
But if I browse the URL I am getting error:

```
<Errors>
<Error>
<errorCode>INVALID_SESSION_ID</errorCode>
<message>Session expired or invalid</message>
</Error>
</Errors>
```

Below is the URL:

```
https://myinstance.salesforce.com/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/ID
```

Another URL:

```
https://myinstance.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/Account/ID
```

I have also written an apex class to get User Name based on ID:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/User/*')
global with sharing class UserManagerAPI 
{
    @HttpGet
    global static User doGet() 
    {
        RestRequest req = RestContext.request;
        RestResponse res = RestContext.response;
        String userId = req.requestURI.substring(req.requestURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        User result = [SELECT Name FROM User WHERE Id = :userId];
        return result;
    }

}
```

How do I share the URL for this API via Apex class to anyone who wants to use the API?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're following [Apex web services](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/content/learn/modules/apex_integration_services/apex_integration_webservices) trailhead module and your UserManagerAPI is correct. When constructing a URL for a custom REST service, you [determine your instance](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000322728&type=1&mode=1) and then append `/services/apexrest/<your REST resource>`. For your `UserManagerAPI` service, the resource is `/User` so the full service URL is `https://<myInstance>.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/User`.

By default a custom REST service follows the same security semantics as do many out of the box Salesforce APIs. That is, a caller must provide an access token to call the API. The access token must be obtained via an oAuth grant. From [Understanding Authentication](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/intro_understanding_authentication.htm):

> Before making REST API calls, you must authenticate the application
>   user using OAuth 2.0. To do so, you’ll need to:
>
> 1. Set up your application as a connected app in the Salesforce organization.
> 2. Determine the correct Salesforce OAuth endpoint for your connected app to use.
> 3. Authenticate the connected app user via one of several different OAuth 2.0 authentication flows.

The grant is authorized based on a combination of client id/credentials/etc and a user account in Salesforce. The user account is attached to a license + profile; together these two items confer certain privileges on a user. If you're using a cheap license or a profile with insufficient privileges, you might see `Session expired or invalid` error message.

The other, more benign possibility is that you've done all of the above and obtained the access token in a valid manner but the token did expire. In this case you'd just need to obtain a fresh token by repeating the oAuth grant flow.

Regarding your attempt to call the standard REST service on the Account object, `/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account` is a valid resource. `/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/ID` is NOT a valid resource but `/services/data/v45.0/sobjects/Account/{ID}` where `{ID}` is an Account record ID will work.